# Web scaping from URL based on start/end HTML elements

Tags: xml, web-scraping

I'm wondering if there's a software (OSX or Win) that you can content scrape a website by specifying a start/end tag in the DOM and only grabbing the HTML between them? Ideally one that will export said content to XML or CSV?

Comment: Software requests are off-topic for Stackoverflow ("asking for off-site resources and tool recommendations")

Comment: Most scrapers can do this if they support CSS selectors. I'm using Goutte with PHP - it's a headless browser rather than a scraper _per se_ - but it does this very well. One specifies a an outer tag, rather than a start/end (since content has to be opened and closed by the same tag).

Comment: @halfer: You do not *have to* open and close with the same tag, e.g. when you want to get all rows of a table between specific rows. And that case is just impossible to handle with pure CSS. And although XPath can do it, it becomes very ugly

Comment: I have a custom tool I built years ago but unfortunately it was used as a migration tool and the scope of its export was to a very proprietary CMS. It even cleaned up the HTML, remembered page path and hierarchy etc. Was hoping there was a tool out there that did similar but with a more generic export in multiple formats. The closest tool I could find was Web Content Extractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My  [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) can do something like that. E.g. you can get all divs between the divs with id `foo`  and `bar` with:

```
<div id="foo"/>
<div>{.}</div>*
<div id="bar"/>
```

It uses pattern matching for this, so you can have arbitrary many start/end elements with arbitrary complexity